React not activating custom addEventListener for 'DOMContentLoaded' to uniformly add attribute to all specified elements
In our React app we need a cross-cutting way to set an HTML attribute on an element with a given class, across all components when they are rendered or re-rendered.
We tried using the DOMContentLoaded event as follows:
In the top-level component, there is an initialization effect:
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          console.log('DOMContentLoaded event');
          const divElements = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');
          if(divElements){
            divElements.forEach(div => {
              div.removeAttribute('role');
              div.setAttribute('role', 'presentation');
            });
          }
    });
   }, []);

But React doesn't honor this event declaration and nothing happens; the console statement isn't printed.
What would be a good way to accomplish this task?

By the time React runs, the DOM is almost certainly already done. Otherwise React wouldn't be able to rehydrate your page. Just run the code in your effect instead of trying to set up a listener.

Which is why I'm soliciting ideas on other ideas how to accomplish this.

Simply remove the listener wrapper. useEffect(() => { const divElements ..... }, []). But if you're doing this to change React-managed DOM nodes, you probably don't want to do this because the DOM reflects component state, not the other way around. So Instead, you probably want your own event (i.e. have all components that need to set these attributes listen for a custom event, and dispatch that as needed so that all components can properly update their state) or a cascading property that tells descendants whether to include that role or not.

But what would be the dependencies of this effect? We have to do it whenever the DOM changes, but it's not any of our state variables that we can track. That's why I asked about a generic way to do it.

What does "when the DOM changes" mean, when it sounds like that the entire DOM is managed by React? That's just "literally any time React renders anything"?
